# countdown timer in android studio

Tags: java, android

why my countdown timer in level 1 continuously run when i move to the next level/activity? pls help me!!! :( i'm a newbie in programming

```
int secondsRemaining = 30;
CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

    @Override

    public void onTick(long l) {

        secondsRemaining --;

        tv_timer.setText(Integer.toString(secondsRemaining) + "sec");

    }

    @Override

    public void onFinish() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(easyQuiz1.this, TryAgain1.class);

        startActivity(intent);

        finish();

    }

}.start();
```

Comment: what about the secondsRemaining on the public void onTick???

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, Please add proper/entire code of your activity.

I think your code was not right you have to check this demo https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/countdowntimer-in-android-with-example/ and improve your code. You take **secondsRemaining** variable unnecessary.